# Chrome debugger jumps to wrong file on breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, chrome-debugging

I got a vue-js application with multiple components called `index.vue`, some nested, loaded at the same time. When I set a breakpoint in Chrome inspector in one of the `index.vue` files, the debugger halts correctly but opens up the wrong `index.vue` files. It seems to be related to Webpack sourcemaps config as turning this off files are opened correctly in debugger.

Comment: did you ever manage to solve this? facing the exact same thing

Comment: worked around just writing "debugger" in the source.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too as I was fooling around with debugger keyword. Looks like that throughout the breakpoints chain, if you re-run with an extra (or missing if you have more than 1) debugger keyword, then the breakpoint stops on the correct file!
Crazy dirty workaround but it seems to work for me when not even disabling chrome cache did.